# I'm getting the following error when trying to upgrade the version of Angular CLI from 1.7.3 to 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

```
My setup ->

    Angular CLI: 1.7.3
    Node: 10.15.3
    OS: darwin x64
    Angular: 5.2.9
    ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... http, language-service, platform-browser
    ... platform-browser-dynamic, router

    @angular/cli: 1.7.3
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
    @angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
    @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
    @ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
    @ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
    @schematics/angular: 0.3.2
    @schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
    typescript: 2.4.2
    webpack: 3.11.0

iMac-de-Rafael:project rafa$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest -save-dev
Password:
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> fsevents@1.2.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.8 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib' 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Try deleting node_nodules and run it again. No sudo needed.

Comment: I try, gave the same error